# Android: Looking for afterRefresh or afterDraw on ListView

Tags: android, events, listview

I'm looking for an event that will occur right after the ListView, or one of it's childs, has been redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such event, the only way afaik is to override ListView.draw()